# Save a text string to textbox with keyboard shortcut

Tags: c#, textbox, save, keyboard-shortcuts

Im a beginner in C# and im trying to create a windows form application that save a copied text to a textbox when you execute a command with the keyboard. I know there is mouch more to do but where do i start? I suceed to make someting happening with the code below a start at least.. 
And another question.. is it possible to create more than 2 commands. It doesn't work if i add for example : " && KeyCode.ToString() == "B")  "

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "C")
        {

           MessageBox.Show("CTRL+C");
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You would manage this by calling keyDown/Up events. Keep track of each event and which key went down. Then using the Clipboard.GetText() function to copy/paste the text from clipboard into your textbox once both keys are down.

Example,

```
bool keyup = false;
bool keyleft = false;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        keyup = true;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        keyleft = true;
    }

    if (keyleft && keyup)
    {
        textboxOne.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
    }
}


private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        keyup = false;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        keyleft = false;
    }
}
```

Used both these as my resources.
Resource One: [Detect when two keys are pressed at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536368/detect-when-two-keys-are-pressed-at-the-same-time)
Resource Two: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx